# How to get Public URL of media from user Google Drive using react-google-drive-picker in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-drive-api

I want the public URL of the user's Google Drive media. So I can store that content in databases to easily access and save storage size

```js
const handleOpenPicker = () => {
    openPicker({
      clientId:
        "******",
      developerKey: "******",
      viewId: "DOCS_IMAGES_AND_VIDEOS",
      showUploadView: true,
      showUploadFolders: true,
      supportDrives: true,
      multiselect: true,
      
      customScopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
      callbackFunction: (data) => {
        if (data.action === "picked") {
          mutation.mutate(data.docs);
        }
      },
    });
  };
```